# how to achieve this filter UI using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

how to implement this UI using flutter?

i try to add dropdownbutton to appBar. Adding Row widget with textfield and icon.
but the how to minimize textfield width?
how to make container as same height as textfield?.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- To make children of Row have the same height, you have to wrap Row with IntrinsicHeight and set crossAxisAlignment to CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

[image]

- Example Code

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder()
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue
                  ),
                  child: Icon(Icons.menu),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  final searchAndFilterRowHeight = 50.0; //desired height for search field and the filter (blue) container

     SizedBox(
            height: searchAndFilterRowHeight,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  hintText: "Search here",
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                ))),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Container(
                  width: searchAndFilterRowHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Icon(
                    Icons.format_align_left_sharp,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```